# How to get both the output of the time command in a file?

Tags: bash, redirect

I ran the command `time echo "Hello world" | tee output.txt` expecting to get the full output to both terminal `stdout` and the `output.txt` file. However, the file content is not what I expect :

**Expected file content:**

Hello world

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

**Actual content:**

Hello world"

can anyone help ?

Comment: [How can I redirect the output of 'time' to a variable or file?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032), *call `time` in a SubShell or block* is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In bash, [`time` is a keyword](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) which applies to pipelines as a whole. So, `time echo "Hello world" | tee output.txt` is timing the entirety of `echo "Hello world" | tee output.txt`, and not just the `echo` command. Also, it writes the time statistics to stderr. So we need to:

1. Group the commands so that `time` applies to the command or the part of the pipeline we're concerned about.
2. Redirect stderr stream of that group into stdout.
3. And then pipe the output to tee.

So, one of:

```
(time echo "Hello world") 2>&1 | tee output.txt
{ time echo "Hello world"; } 2>&1 | tee output.txt
```

Here:

- we need to take (time echo) as a single command so use parentheses or braces,
- redirected stderr to stdout,
- piped stdout to `tee`.

We can also use `|&` as a shortcut for `2>&1 |`:

```
(time echo "Hello world") |& tee output.txt
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. It worked

Comment: Those are really *parentheses* not braces, and cause the commands to be executed in a subshell. You can actually use braces instead, which avoids the subshell: `{ time echo "Hello world"; } 2>&1`. Note the whitespace and extra `;` which is necessary when written as a one-liner.

Comment: @steeldriver updated.

Comment: ... I didn't mean to imply that your original answer was incorrect - just that there's another way to do it (at least in bash)

Comment: @steeldriver ok

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @dome, what system you are using. Still working on my computer.